# Bootstrap data table from a JSON without array

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap

I have been looking into designing my UI with bootstrap table. My simple HTML utilizes bootstrap table features to render a response from REST service.Everything looks good as long as my REST service responds with list of objects as a JSON array. 
My question: How do I use bootstrap table if the response JSON does contain only a single element.

Sample response JSON that works:

```
{
 "parent":
          [{
           "id":1,
           "name":"some_name",
           "city":"some_city"
          }]
}
```

Sample JSON response that I am struggling to display:

```
{
 "parent":
          {
           "id":1,
           "name":"some_name",
           "city":"some_city"
          }
}
```

I tried one workaround to fix this by appending array brackets in the JSON response using following:

```
function responseHandler(res) {  //this function is called from table element       
    return JSON.parse("["+JSON.stringify(res.parent)+"]");                      
}
```

However, I don't really like this solution as it looks like making things work without a systematic approach.

Based on my research, I am pretty convinced that bootstrap table requires the JSON data in JSON array format. I have run some tests and it confirms this finding. 
I would like to know how do I achieve showing single element JSON response using bootstrap-table features like "data-url" annd "data-response-handler".

My HTML looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap Template</title>           
<script src="bootstrap-table-master/docs/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-table-master/docs/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js">   
</script>
<script src="bootstrap-table-master/dist/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-table-master/docs/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-table-master/docs/assetsbootstrap/css/bootstrap-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-table-master/dist/bootstrap-table.css">
<script>    
function responseHandler(res) {         
    return JSON.parse("["+JSON.stringify(res.parent)+"]");                      
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Bootstrap Table</h1>
    <table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-url="mydata.json" data-height="699" data-response-handler="responseHandler">      
        <thead>
            <tr>                
                <th data-field="id">ID</th>                 
                <th data-field="name">Name</th>                 
                <th data-field="city">City</th>
            </tr>
        </thead> 
    </table>        
</body>
</html>
```